# Download de dois arquivos Zipados em PHP

Tags: php, php-7, phpexcel

Estou tentando compactar dois arquivos junto em PHP, porém recebo o seguinte erro ao tentar abrir o .zip:

```
!   C:\Users\gpsilva\Downloads\your_name (19).zip: Final inesperado do arquivo
```

Este problema acontece apenas quando eu adiciono o segundo arquivo. Quando tem apenas um, o problema não acontece e eu consigo abrir o .zip normalmente.

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls($spreadsheet);
$excel_file_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", 'DGO-Acesso');
$writer->save($excel_file_tmp);

//zip
$zip_file_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", 'DGO');
$zip        = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_file_tmp, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->addFile($excel_file_tmp, 'DGO-Acesso.xls');
$zip->close();

//download
$download_filename = 'DGO-Download.zip'; 
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_tmp));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $download_filename . "\"");
readfile($zip_file_tmp);
unlink($excel_file_tmp);
unlink($zip_file_tmp);
die;
```

Se eu duplico esta linha:

```
$zip->addFile($excel_file_tmp, 'DGO-Acesso2.xls');
```

Mudando apenas o nome do arquivo, para vir os dois zipados, o erro já começa a acontecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código parece estar correto, mas provavelmente o erro tem a ver com o fato de que você não está especificando o formato do nome do arquivo.

Veja seu código reformulado:

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls($spreadsheet);
$excel_file_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", 'DGO-Acesso');
$writer->save($excel_file_tmp);

//zip
$current_dir = dirname( __FILE__ );
//$zip_file_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", 'DGO');
$zip_file_tmp = uniqid( 'DGO' );
$zip_file_tmp .= '.zip';
$zip        = new ZipArchive();
//$zip->open($zip_file_tmp, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->open($zip_file_tmp, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile($excel_file_tmp, 'DGO-Acesso.xls');
$zip->addFile($excel_file_tmp, 'DGO-Acesso2.xls');
$zip->close();

//download
$download_filename = 'DGO-Download.zip';
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_tmp));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $download_filename . "\"");
readfile($zip_file_tmp);
@unlink($excel_file_tmp);
@unlink($zip_file_tmp);
die;
```

**Alguns pontos:**

1. Quando você usa a função `tempnam()` ela automaticamente cria um arquivo, e nesse caso é mais interessante você usar algo como a função `uniqid()` que te **retorna** uma string única.
2. E uma vez que o nome do arquivo sempre será único, faz-se necessário o uso de `ZipArchive::CREATE`.

Testei aqui e deu tudo certo.

Faça os testes na sua máquina.

Comment: @felipecsweb O erro persiste, se eu tiro uma das linha de add ele volta a funcionar, mas obrigado pelas dicas de melhoria!
Vou continuar caçando o erro :(

Comment: O Problema estava no  "header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_tmp));" , por algum motivo o size do header estava ficando menor do que o size real do arquivo zipado e por isso o download era feito faltando "pedaços", a solução foi apenas comentar esta linha.